# ActiveMQ - How to remove messages from kahadb db.data file

Tags: activemq-classic

I sent 1.000.000 object messages to the queue, and my kahadb's db.data file became 480 mb. Then my consumer started to get messages. After a while consuming finished and all messages in the queue reached to the target. But when I checked my db.data file, it was still 480 mb. Thats why I want to delete consumed messages.

How can I do that. Is there any property to delete automatically

Comment: possible duplicate of [ActiveMQ - How to set max size of kahadb db.data file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151915/activemq-how-to-set-max-size-of-kahadb-db-data-file)

Answer (score 2):

Manually you can purge queued messages in the web console `http://localhost:8161/`
http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-purge-a-queue.html

Automatically you can discard expired messages with `<sharedDeadLetterStrategy processExpired="false" />` 
http://activemq.apache.org/message-redelivery-and-dlq-handling.html