# ActiveMQ - How to set max size of kahadb db.data file

Tags: activemq-classic

I set ActiveMQ broker SystemUsage property as below;

```
SystemUsage systemUsage=new SystemUsage();

StoreUsage storeUsage=new StoreUsage();
storeUsage.setLimit(1L);            
systemUsage.setStoreUsage(storeUsage);

MemoryUsage memoryUsage =new MemoryUsage();
memoryUsage.setLimit(1L);
systemUsage.setMemoryUsage(memoryUsage);

TempUsage tempUsage=new TempUsage();
tempUsage.setLimit(1L);
systemUsage.setTempUsage(tempUsage);

broker.setSystemUsage(systemUsage); 

broker.start();
```

but my db.data file goes on growing up.But I have to restrict it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no max size setting for the db.data file.  It will grow as large as it needs to in order to handle the amount of state data needed to run the Broker.  It will however recycle unused portions as things change on the Broker so it should reach a stable point that accommodates your use case.